# I think I stuffed up my external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, crash

As in the title, I can't get it to work. I should probably say, it's an internal HDD in an External case.

Last night I was working on copying old files off it onto my new computer, however, somehow, it crashed my computer about halfway into copying 58gb of data (approx).

Now when I plug it in, my computer recognises it, but doesn't let me open it. It shows up as Local Disk (F:) like normal, but with no data bar below it, like my main internal HDD.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it's device driver and trying it on different computers, but to no avail.

Have I completely stuffed it up, or am I just not doing something right?

Comment: I guess it's too late.. But sometimes you can still access the NTFS/FAT filesystem in Linux even if it fails on Windows. Just sometimes, but still worth a try. It actually did work for me a few weeks ago. Also, even if you formatted your drive, there is still a chance to save your data, at least parts of it. But you have to avoid writes to the drive! Try Recuva or Paragon software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you can format it.

```
Click Startup > Right click Computer > Click Manage > Click Disk Management > Right click the drive you want to manage > Format
```

It's not broken, I'd say that the filesystem is, and needs to be formatted.

Comment: Wait, so I have to format it, but does that remove all the files off of it?

Comment: Ah! Screw it! I got most stuff off it two days ago, I'll just format it then... Lucky I got the photos and stuff...

Comment: @OneTerrorist Yeah, it removes all stuff from it but I'm afraid it's the only thing you can do for it.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it now.